# in vscode, can I open a directory in the current window via the terminal/cli

Tags: visual-studio-code

As per the title

If I go to the VSCode terminal  and type `code <name of dir>`, it opens the directory in a new VSCode window. I wish there was a way to open it in the current window (perhaps using another command, or choosing some option in preferences)

Is there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a setting not for the command line but for opening a folder from a menu or command:

`Window: Open Folders in New Window`  // set to 'off'

or use the `-r` switch (for 'reuse the same window) in the command line, see [Command Line options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options)

Comment: `code -r <folder-name>` from CLI will open folder in current window

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I've just started using VS Code and found that "code -r ." did the trick. Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ctrl` + `K` + `O` and select a folder to open.